# How to retrieve `--user-data-dir` path in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I know we are able to launch chrome and specify which Chrome Profile to use by adding the `--user-data-dir` flag when launching as such:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project\TestChromeProfile"
```

However, I'm wondering if there's any way we could get that `--user-data-dir` path in the browser by executing a code.

Perhaps something like this?

```
chrome.runtime.getProfilePath(); 
//Returns the path
```

Comment: What would you do with this information? JS can't access files directly.

Comment: I want to get the folder name: `TestChromeProfile`. I have a config file that changes very frequently and I would like to pass this file to a Chrome Extension. As JS can't access local files, the only way would be to fetch it from a Server. But the Chrome Extension first needs to know which file to look for, hence fetching the folder name.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the path? Because I know it can be found in the `chrome://version` page